# Need to understand the problem in AtomicInteger code usage in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, atomicinteger

In one of the interview, a coding question was asked to me and I had to find the problem in that code and suggest proper solution.

Please find below the entire code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Atomic {

    static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static int counter = 0;

    public static class Runnable extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (count.getAndSet(1) != 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        counter = counter + 1;
        count.set(0);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable();
        executor.execute(runnable);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}

}
```

This code is running properly. But question is , there is some problem in this code if number of threads get increased or if I run For loop for almost 10000 times.

I tried to find the problem, but couldn't find one.

Comment: Hint: What might happen if two threads try to increment `counter` at the same time?

Comment: A non-functional issue in this code is "`public static class Runnable extends Thread {`". That *works*, but oof, that's really not a good idea, in at least 2 ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this code. You've not stated with "there is some problem" means, but here are the things that jump out.

---

Firstly, the `counter` variable is not updated safely. Multiple threads don't have guaranteed visibility of the last-written value; nor do you have the guarantee that no other thread has updated its value in between the read and the write.

The simple solution to this: change `counter` to an `AtomicInteger`, and use `getAndIncrement` or `incrementAndGet` to increment it.

---

Secondly, `public static class Runnable extends Thread {` is *extremely* dubious.

1. Don't hide the names of commonly-known Java classes (this is hiding `java.lang.Runnable`)
2. Don't extend `Thread` directly, especially when all you need is a `java.lang.Runnable` to add execute with an `ExecutorService`.

A more suitable class declaration would be:

```
public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
```

(or whatever you want to call it)

Or you can just declare an anonymous class:

```
executor.execute(new Runnable() { /* body */ });
```

Or you can just declare a lambda:

```
executor.execute(() -> { /* body */ });
```

---

Thirdly, `count` doesn't really seem to be serving an obvious purpose here. The logic of the runnable seems to be:

- If "flag" is false:

  1. Set "flag" to true
  2. Increment a variable
  3. Set "flag" to false
- Otherwise:

  1. Wait 3 seconds
  2. Try again

`count` is playing the role of "flag" here. It's effectively just an `AtomicBoolean`.

But you don't need a separate `count` variable at all, if you make the `counter` an `AtomicInteger`:

```
while (true) {
  int current = counter.get();
  if (counter.compareAndSet(current, current + 1)) {
    // Nothing else is trying to update "current" at the same time:
    // we updated it. Stop.
    break;
  }

  // Something else is trying to update at the same time.
  // Sleep for 3 seconds.
  Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```